# Unable to fetch file(openfoam240) from sourceforge

Tags: apt, software-installation, software-sources, add-apt-repository

I tried to install openfoam240 using the instruction given by [Official Website](http://www.openfoam.org/download/ubuntu.php), and I followed the instruction step by step.

but I experienced an error that was showing the deb package could not be fetch:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://www.openfoam.org/download/ubuntu/./dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/openfoam240_0-1_i386.deb  503  Service Unavailable
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

when I put the link into a web browser it redirected me to download.sorceforge.net and showed error below:

[image]

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Using Ubuntu 14.04? What command gave you this error ?

Comment: yes, it's so dude!  sudo apt-get install openfoam240

Comment: What command gave you this error ?

Comment: sudo apt-get install openfoam240

Comment: That's your proxy server not being available...

Comment: I myself think  so, but  any proxy software available? or should I find a mirror for this file?

Comment: Try the answer from A.B. as it uses a different domain, failing that I'd contact your admin if I were you because of DNS issues...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution:

there is a mirror which contains the Deb Files for this version of OpenFoam (2.4.0) 
Here is the link:

[University of Kent Mirror Service](http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/f/project/fo/foam/foam/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/)

Comment: Please inform me if more detail is needed.